# moving on to the next condition within a loop after the previous condition is met

Tags: python

I try to iterate j over the first condition. Only if the first if-statement is not true for every j in range(5) then I want j to iterate over the next condition.

General problem:

```
my_list = []
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(5):
            if #condition == True:
                 #append something to my_list for only one j in range(5)
                 break # move on to the next i
            elif #other condition == True:
                 #append something to my_list for only one j in range(5)
                 break # move on to the next i
```

Example:

```
my_list = []
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(5):
        if j == 3:
            my_list.append(j)
            break
        elif j == 0:
            my_list.append(j)
            break         
my_list
```

Output: `[0, 0, 0]`

What I want as output: `[3, 3, 3]`

Comment: If you want to iterate inside the if than maybe _put the loop inside_?

Answer (score 1):

The expected logic is not fully clear, but IIUC, you want to achieve a mechanism where your use one condition until it is met, then change to another one?

You can maybe use a single comparison with a list holding the conditions?

```
my_list = []
for i in range(3):
    conds = [3,0]       # list of conditions
    cond = conds.pop(0) # start with first one
    for j in range(5):
        if j == cond:   # if condition is met
            my_list.append(j) # store value
            if conds:   # if conditions are remaining
                cond = conds.pop(0) # use the next one
            else:       # else terminate the sub-loop
                break
```

output: `[3, 3, 3]`

Comment: this doesnt work if you want to do the inverse, ie `conds=[1, 2]`

Comment: @TomMcLean depends on the data, I guess the point it to make an ordered match, so if you use a range and the `2` condition is before `1` then you probably shouldn't have a match? I imagine this is just a dummy example, and if really OP wanted to test things such as what you described then loops are not the appropriate tool (you should use sets/dictionaries)

Comment: I'm trying to apply this to a more complex code where I need to run over the first condition for the entire range before moving on to the next condition. I may be able to send this code, but I don't know if it's useful.

Comment: What you should provide is a more concrete example (not just simple ranges)

Comment: I understand that this is not a good example, but I find it very difficult to come up with another example. Is it okay if I share the code I want to apply it to so we can try to figure it out?

Comment: you can always share it, but not sure if anyone will have the time/courage to read it depending on the complexity ;)

Comment: I understand, but I will give it a shot ;)

Comment: I have added my code in the question.

Comment: OK, I see this is a (pandas?) dataframe question, then unless you really have an unorthodox computation, I bet you can do things without a loop. Why don't you give a sample input dataframe, the matching output and a brief description of the logic?

Comment: It is pandas, indeed

Comment: I pressed send too quickly, read the updated comment